# How to configure Worklight Push to MPNS unauthenticated

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mpns

I have not found any way to configure unauthenticated MPNS push on Worklight 6.

The knowledge center only talks about authenticated web services.

So - can Worklight do unauthenticated web services to MPNS and if yes, how to configure them?

Thanks

Jerry

Answer (score 0):

Worklight can handle both authenticated and non-authenticated push notifications in Windows Phone 8.

This is stated [in the Push Notifications training module](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v620/08_01_Push_notifications_in_hybrid_applications.pdf) (slide #52).
It might need further clarifications in the Knowledge Center.

> To send push notifications to Windows Phone 8 devices, you must  use
>   the Microsoft Push Notifications Service (MPNS).
>
> - Non-authenticated push notification does not require any setup from  the developer.
> - Authenticated push notification requires a Windows Phone Dev  Center
>     account.
> - To use authenticated push, you must use a certificate that
>     is issued  by a Microsoft-trusted root certificate authority.